# UNITY C# Screenshot issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write some code to take screenshot and save them in android default DCIM path, first part for take screenshot works but second part for move file to Path not work.

```
public class IS_Screenshot : MonoBehaviour
{
    string ScreenShotFile;

    void Start () 
    {
        ScreenShotFile = Application.persistentDataPath + "_Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png";
        Debug.Log (ScreenShotFile);
    }

    public void Screen_Shot() 
    {
        try
        {
            Application.CaptureScreenshot(ScreenShotFile);

            string Path = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/" + "_Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_") + ".png";
            Debug.Log (Path);

            if(System.IO.File.Exists(ScreenShotFile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(ScreenShotFile, Path);
                Debug.Log ("Screenshot file saved.");
            }
            else
            {               
                Debug.Log ("Screenshot file not found.");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("Screenshot capture failed. | " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Or just "Screenshot file not found"?

Comment: Not any error, file not found just

Comment: In unity editor run mode files stored in this folder "C:\Users\Seven\AppData\LocalLow\ITCO". but in android i couldn't find them.

Comment: And what happens if you remove the `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/` in Path? Will it still say screenshot file not found? I've never tried to take a screenshot, but if `ScreenShotFile` does exist in the editor, but not on android, maybe it's not making the screenshot?

Comment: Also you shouldn't set the `ScreenShotFile` string in `Start` because then it will have a different value than in `Screen_Shot()`

Comment: there is no "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/ " path in pc it must show file not found but after compile in android it must work. problem is in android and where i don't know.

Comment: Well `Application.CaptureScreenshot(ScreenShotFile);` saves the screenshot to `Android/Data/com.yourcompany.appname/Files/` check if your file is there. And again, don't set `ScreenShotFile` in `Start`, set it in `Screen_Shot()` or it will always say `Screenshot file not found`.

Comment: there is no file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.Combine` to attach the filename to the `persistentDataPath`. It may well be that on Android the value of `persistentDataPath` does not end in a path seperator, which will result in an invalid path.

```
ScreenShotFile = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "_Screenshot_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".png");
```

Comment: CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition for `Combine' and no extension method `Combine' of type `string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)